# Covering the plane by circles centered on a discrete set

Tags: combinatorics, plane-geometry, combinatorial-geometry, discrete-geometry

I have the following combinatorial/discrete analysis problem that arose while I was working on a problem in complex analysis, which in turn came from a problem in time-frequency analysis.

Let $\Lambda\subset\mathbb{C}$ be a given uniformly discrete set. Does there exist an $\epsilon>0$ and a uniformly discrete set $\Lambda'\supset\Lambda$ such that $$ \bigcup_{w\in\Lambda'}B(w,f(\Lambda',w)-\epsilon)=\mathbb{C},$$
where $f(\Lambda',w)=\min\{|w'-w|:w'\in \Lambda'\setminus\{w\}\}$. By $S\subset\mathbb{C}$ uniformly discrete I mean a set such that $\inf\{|w_1-w_2|:w_1,w_2\in S, w_1\neq w_2\}>0$.

This has an easy solution if we assume that $\Lambda$ is constrained to a square grid of positive mesh, which is actually all that I needed for the original problem, but I would be nice to know if the general result is true.

Comment: It seems I'm missing something, what if $\Lambda = \{0, 1\}$?

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand the problem because the answer seems like a trivial "no" to me: if $w, w'$ are in minimal distance to each other, then $(w + w')/2$ is not in your union.

Comment: Why is $f(\Lambda', w)$ defined with reference to $\Lambda$ and not $\Lambda'$?  There's a typo, I guess, but I don't know what you're intending to say.

Comment: Indeed there was a typo in the definition of $f$. I have now corrected it.